# Who is <admin> for install.php during Mediawiki install?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm installing [Mediawiki 1.31](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download) on CentOS 7. I'm following the instructions at [Manual:Installing_MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installing_MediaWiki). I'm having a trouble running `install.php`.

An earlier step had me create the MySQL database using:

```
CREATE DATABASE wikidb;
CREATE USER 'wikiuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wikidb.* TO 'wikiuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Next, I am suppose to run `php maintenance/install.php`. However, they omit instructions on how to do so. The script is failing with:

```
# php maintenance/install.php
Argument <admin> required!

CLI-based MediaWiki installation and configuration.
Default options are indicated in parentheses.
...

Arguments:
    [name]: The name of the wiki (MediaWiki)
    <admin>: The username of the wiki administrator.
```

My question is, who is `<admin>`? Is it root on this machine? Is it `wikiuser` from the previous step? Or do I need to create another user and give it root privileges for the database? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It is the MediaWiki username you want to give your first user. It's a largely arbitrary up-to-255-byte string (there are a few banned characters like `@#<>|`).

You know there is a much more user-friendly web installer, right?

Comment: Thanks Tgr. I don't know about the user friendly web installer. The wiki still does not work: [https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/). Nothing but a blank page even though logging and exceptions are enabled. Apache logs showing 500 server error.

Comment: You should just uncompress the tarball into a web-accessible directory, open that directory in a web browser, and the web installer will take you from there.